# How to remove text-decoration when li is a hyperlink

Tags: css, list, hyperlink

Here is the CSS

```
.ulLink{
text-decoration: none;      
color: grey;
}
```

Here is html

```
<ul id="myResources">
   <a class="ulLink" href="http://www.acterra.org/greenteams/bottledwater.html"> <li>http://www.acterra.org/greenteams/bottledwater.html</li></a>
   <a class="ulLink" href="http://www.ewg.org/research/chlorine-pollutants-high-levels-dc-  tap-water"><li>http://www.ewg.org/research/chlorine-pollutants-high-levels-dc-tap- water</li></a>
   <a class="ulLink" href="http://www.statisticbrain.com/attention-span-statistics/">   <li>http://www.statisticbrain.com/attention-span-statistics/</li></a>
</ul>
```

Tried using the id from the ul and then putting that still dint work.

```
#myResources {
    text-decoration: none
}
```

Comment: Dont put link <a> before <li>

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML is très invalid; `<li>`s must be direct descendants of the list. Fix those, and your CSS should work.

```
<ul id="myResources">
   <li><a class="ulLink" href="http://www.acterra.org/greenteams/bottledwater.html"> http://www.acterra.org/greenteams/bottledwater.html</a></li>
   <li><a class="ulLink" href="http://www.ewg.org/research/chlorine-pollutants-high-levels-dc-  tap-water">http://www.ewg.org/research/chlorine-pollutants-high-levels-dc-tap- water</a></li>
   <li><a class="ulLink" href="http://www.statisticbrain.com/attention-span-statistics/">   http://www.statisticbrain.com/attention-span-statistics/</a></li>
</ul>
```

Removing the spaces between `dc-` and `tap-water` couldn’t hurt either.

Answer (score 1):

Dont put link `a` before `li`

```
<ul id="myResources">
   <li><a class="ulLink" href="http://www.acterra.org/greenteams/bottledwater.html"> http://www.acterra.org/greenteams/bottledwater.html</a></li>
   <li><a class="ulLink" href="http://www.ewg.org/research/chlorine-pollutants-high-levels-dc-tap-water">http://www.ewg.org/research/chlorine-pollutants-high-levels-dc-tap- water</a></li>
   <li><a class="ulLink" href="http://www.statisticbrain.com/attention-span-statistics/">   http://www.statisticbrain.com/attention-span-statistics/</a></li>
</ul>
```

Use above `HTML`